# How to make from List<ClassName> two strings array (Names, Values)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I've the following class:

```
class Node
{
   public string NameField{ get; set; }
   public string ValueField{ get; set; }
}
```

And also have a list of Nodes as `var test = new List<Node>`, I need to make two strings arrays as `string[]`, first contains all the NameField and the second contains all the ValueField, I did the following code:

```
    string[] NameField = new string[test.Count];
    string[] ValueField = new string[test.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var s in prefsNameValueArray)
    {
        NameField[i] = s.CTMAttrName;
        ValueField[i] = s.CTMAttrValue;
        i++;
    }
```

Can I do the same using LINQ, can anybody help me to improve this code?

Thanks in advance,
Ramzy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linq:

```
string[] NameFields = nodes.Select(n => n.NameField).ToArray();
string[] ValueFields = nodes.Select(n => n.ValueField).ToArray();
```

Linq is not necessarily the most efficient way here since `ToArray` could create an array which may be too large(due to the doubling algorithm) if you use a query instead of a collection. But it is short and readable (and fast enough mostly).

This is the for-loop version:

```
int count = nodes.Count(); // in case you want to change the collection type or use a linq query
string[] NameField = new string[count];
string[] ValueField = new string[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    NameField[i] = nodes.ElementAt(i).NameField;
    ValueField[i] = nodes.ElementAt(i).ValueField;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nameField = test.Select(n => n.CTMAttrName).ToArray();
var valueField = test.Select(n => n.CTMAttrValue).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Lambda expressions`;

```
string[] NameField = prefsNameValueArray.Select(x=> x.NameField).ToArray();
string[] ValueField = prefsNameValueArray.Select(x=> x.ValueField).ToArray();
```